# .NET - get session variables key "contains"

Tags: .net, loops, session, where-clause, contains

I store many objects in session.

One asynchronous method puts values into session: `Session.Add("Mark_" + randomString, value);`

I want to write another method to other thread which is getting all session values with `Mark_` at the beginning of the key. How to search through this? Session is unable to be list, foreach/for doesn't let me check the key, only returns the value.

For example:

session has 3 keys:

`Mark_123123dsf`
`Mark_dfgi2i34h`
`OtherKey`

I want to get values of `Mark_123123dsf` and `Mark_dfgi2i34h` by searching session by `Mark_`

Answer (score 0):

Session object stores Key-Value pairs. You can iterate Session keys and get related values using;

```
foreach (string sessionKey in Session.Keys)
{
     var someValue = Session[sessionKey];
}
```

However; you cannot execute queries (i.e. Linq) on Keys collection since it does not implement required interfaces such as IQueryable. If you really need such a feature, you need to index your keys and have to implement it by yourself.